# How to add Row to dataGridView from user control

Tags: c#, datagridview, user-controls, row

I have this form with a button and َPanel. When I press the button I want to add a Row to `dataGridView1`

[image]

User control code:

```cs
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    private static UserControl1 _instance;
    public static UserControl1 Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new UserControl1();
            return _instance;
        }
    }
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void setRow()
    {
        String[] row = { "TEST", "TEST", "TEST", "TEST" };
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

Form1 code:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        panel1.Controls.Add(new UserControl1());
        UserControl1.Instance.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        UserControl1.Instance.BringToFront();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl1 user = new UserControl1();
        user.setRow();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new instance of ``UserControl1`` in your button click event? Call ``UserControl1.Instance.setRow();`` instead

Comment: to  access  a method setRow() in UserControl1

Comment: No... to display UserControl in Form1 you are creating the instance in constructor... with ``panel1.Controls.Add(new UserControl1());``

Comment: this method in user Control  public void setRow()
    {
        String[] row = { "TEST", "TEST", "TEST", "TEST" };
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserControl1 user = new UserControl1();
    user.setRow();
}
```

Should be

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserControl1.Instance.setRow();
}
```

and constructor of UserControl1 should look like

```
public UserControl1()
{
    _instance = this;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

In your code you are creating 3 instances of your UserControl and it seems like you want to only have one. When you call a method on one of those instances it doesnt in no way influence the other instances.